# Compiler options to disable C++ “features”

Tags: c++

Is it possible to pass a compiler (e.g., g++, clang, etc.) flags or defines that will disable certain “features” of C++ as a means of quality control?

I’d love to disable multiple inheritance and a lot of other things in C++ that (I think) do more harm than good.

Comment: Keep in mind that most languages without multiple inheritance at least allow implementing multiple interfaces; C++ does not have interfaces so disabling that could be problematic. I'm not aware of any such switches.

Comment: No, there isn't.  You get access to the entire toolshed, even if you only need a hammer.  Pick another language that doesn't allow multiple class inheritance, like C#, or impose some self-discipline and refrain from using the tools that can cut you.

Comment: What would be the advantage of this? C++, like C, is a language designed with the philosophy that you don't pay for what you don't use. If you don't want multiple inheritance, then don't use it, and it won't cost you anything. Likewise with other language features that you don't like. (At any rate, yes, there are, just not for multiple inheritance. It would help narrow the scope if you'd [edit] the question to ask about a *specific* compiler and/or a *specific* language feature.)

Comment: I don't think a conforming impelemtation can do that. The draft standard says `A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do
not alter the behavior of any well-formed program.`.

Comment: You may still use/write some static analyzer tools to detect some feature usage.

Comment: `I don't think a conforming impelemtation can do that.` `[...]provided they do not alter the behavior of any well-formed program.` I was hoping it would just throw an error saying it was disabled or something. Any other suggestions to achieve something like this?

Comment: Shafik is right, there is no way to do it while still remaining a conforming implementation. As per the C++ language standard, you'll have entered into the realm of undefined behavior. However, that may be irrelevant for your purposes, if the *compiler vendor* defines the behavior. Which they will if they offer such an option. A well-formed C++ program might use exceptions, but if you've disabled them in your compiler, you obviously won't be able to run those programs. Of course, you still haven't told us exactly what you're hoping to achieve and *why*.

Comment: I've heard enough horror stories about bad code introduced to codebases that wouldn't have been if it were in say C, but then C misses certain good features of C++ itself. I suppose static analyzer is the best option so far

Comment: C++ is not mandatory. You are very welcome to use any other language, or design your own and release it onto the world. But once you have decided on C++, you are stuck with C++ as a whole. The language has no "features" to turn on and off at will.

Comment: What would the compiler do for standard library features that use multiple inheritance like `iostream`?

Comment: You can modify `clang` to warn you about any feature you want (provided that you define what constitutes each feature), or do any other program analysis. There is an API in place for that. Bear in mind that any disabled feature might mean you are no longer able to use certain parts of the standard library.

Comment: Could you link to more information on the clang warnings n.m.? That seems perfect

Comment: Maybe you cannot disable whole features, but normally there are lots of warnings available to spot questionable (although technically legal) constructs (e.g. polymorphic classes with non virtual destructor, assignments in conditionals, implicit narrowing conversions, reads from uninitialized variables, wrong format specifiers, octal literals, signature mismatch when attempting to redefine a virtual function, just to say some that saved me several times). Also, almost any compiler has an option to mark (some or all) warnings as errors, it may be a starting point.

Comment: You can sometimes disable features, but the only two I've seen are exceptions and RTTI, and you can't use the standard library if you disable exceptions.

Comment: Multiple inheritance also means additional private base classes, which are used in quite a few idioms, e.g. in the pre-C++11 `boost::noncopyable`. And I'd be interested in what those "lot of other things" are supposed to be. Operator overloading? Then say goodbye to `string1 + string2` and to `myvec[0]`. `reinterpret_cast`? Then you can no longer use many useful C libraries.

Comment: Many years ago I was asked by a university to quote on building such a thing as a front-end to the C++ compiler. To nobody's surprise they did not accept the quote, which was well into six figures. I told them they should be teaching Java instead ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've selected C++ as your language you get C++ as your language. The compiler can't legitimately start rejecting legal C++ programs as a result of some configuration flag.

So one obvious option is to not use C++ but instead pick a language that provides the features and safety considerations that you're interested in.

If you do elect to continue with C++ then understand that the language allows you to shoot yourself in the foot. *This is by design*.

What you can do is hold design reviews, code reviews, and utilize static code checkers and compiler warnings to catch a wide variety of problems at various stages of development.

Comment: _"The compiler can't legitimately start rejecting legal C++ programs as a result of some configuration flag."_ What, like `-fno-exceptions`? That's fairly common, and there's no special rule for exceptions.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit That's a good point: It's a common feature, technically unconforming compiler.

Comment: Turning off exceptions doesn't fully disable them anyway, at least in MSVC

Comment: @paulm: It does in GCC. The code required to unwind the stack is simply not generated.

Comment: @MarkB: Yep; GCC doesn't have an equivalent for multiple inheritance though. Fortunately.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Not really; you can trivially produce a well-formed program whose observable behaviour differs wildly depending on whether exceptions are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You might perhaps customize GCC, e.g. with [MELT](https://web.archive.org/web/20120915210143/https://gcc-melt.org/) (see [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.0779.pdf) paper), to add your additional coding rules validation. However, this is not trivial (probably months of work, even for me, the main author of MELT). Such an hypothetical extension of GCC would emit some of the warnings you want.

So the flags you'll pass will probably start with `-fplugin=melt`; but some additional work is needed (to implement your required GCC extensions in MELT).

In 2023 MELT is obsolete (unless you use an old GCC version), but of course you can develop your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) and reuse some ideas.

<sup>PS. If you are serious enough to be able to put (or buy) months of work around that idea, please contact me.</sup>